# С++: передача произвольных параметров из конструктора класса дальше в методы

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, конструктор, параметры

Подскажите, как можно более правильно и красиво реализовать следующую задачу:

у меня есть класс сбора статистики

```
template<class ICustomStatistics>
class CPeriodicStatistics
```

который универсально работает с разными классами статистик

```
class CStatistics1 : public ICustomStatistics {};
class CStatistics2 : public ICustomStatistics {};
```

Класс `ICustomStatistics` - абстрактный и требует от наследников переопределить главную функцию `ICustomStatistics::add(data_t*)`

Использование (определение) выглядит следующим образом

```
analyze(new CPeriodicStatistics<CStatistics1>(...));
analyze(new CPeriodicStatistics<CStatistics2>(...));
```

Внутри работы `CPeriodicStatistics` регулярно создаются и удаляются объекты `ICustomStatistics`

**Главная проблема**

классы `CStatistics1`, `CStatistics2`, ... имеют разные параметры конструктора
поэтому возникает вопрос - как их правильно передавать в конструктор `CPeriodicStatistics` и потом использовать в методах класса, т.е. выглядит так:

```
analyze(new CPeriodicStatistics<CStatistics1>("file.txt", 10s, 250));
analyze(new CPeriodicStatistics<CStatistics2>(mydata, "output.dat", 30));
```

Т.е. параметры совсем разные могут быть и я их из класса `CPeriodicStatistics` не знаю, да и знать не хочу

Хотелось бы что-то типа

```
template<class ICustomStatistics>
CPeriodicStatistics<ICustomStatistics>::CPeriodicStatistics(...params)
{
    m_params = params;
}

template<class ICustomStatistics>
void
CPeriodicStatistics<ICustomStatistics>::func()
{
    ICustomStatistics* obj = new ICustomStatistics(m_params);
}
```

**Можно ли что-то подобное сделать?**

Потому что не хочется дублировать много кода и создавать лишние классы-прокладки, когда этого можно избежать

Comment: Название параметра шаблона не говорит о том, что интснцироваться будет только класс с таким именем. Зачем вы хотите иметь шаблонный класс?

Comment: @Zhihar "как можно более правильно и красиво", - эх, и это пройдет.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan, потому что я не передаю какой-то объект в класс, класс работает с классом, у которого есть своя начинка и общий метод add()

и внутри класса `CPeriodicStatistics` классы создаются и удаляются многократно

конечно можно добавить `ICustomStatistics` метод `clone` и передавать именно объект, но мне кажется это кривоватенько

Comment: @Cerbo, ну должны же оставаться какие-то идеалы :)  которых надо придерживаться, а делать некрасиво и неправильно я уже умею :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых у вас много путаницы из-за того, что имя параметра шаблона совпадает с именем класса.

Во-вторых имеет смыл передавать в конструктор шаблонного класса некоторый функтор, который будет инкапсулировать в себе параметры для создания экземпляров класса, наследующих от `ICustomStatistics`:

```
template<typename XStatistics> class
CPeriodicStatistics
{
     private: ::std::function<XStatistics (void)> m_make_statistics;

     public: template<typename... XArgs>
     CPeriodicStatistics(XArgs &&... args)
     :   m_make_statistics{::std::forward<XArgs>(args)...}
     { return; }

     public: void
     func(void)
     {
         auto statistics{m_make_statistics()};
     }
};
```

А если возвращать указатель на базовый класс, то CPeriodicStatistics можно и не делать шаблоном:

```
class
CPeriodicStatistics
{
     private: ::std::function<::std::unique_ptr<ICustomStatistics> (void)> m_make_statistics;

     public: template<typename... XArgs>
     CPeriodicStatistics(XArgs &&... args)
     :   m_make_statistics{::std::forward<XArgs>(args)...}
     { return; }

     public: void
     func(void)
     {
         auto p_statistics{m_make_statistics()};
     }
};
```

Comment: вот этого момента не понял "А если возвращать указатель на базовый класс, то CPeriodicStatistics можно и не делать шаблоном:"

класс `CPeriodicStatistics` не знает, что за `ICustomStatistics` будет использоваться (вернее какой из его наследников), поэтому и приходится сделать шаблон

Comment: не совсем понимаю как будет (в случае вашего первого примера) выглядеть такое использование:

в функции func() надо создать массив из 10 объектов `XStatistics`, при создании которым будут переданы соответствующие параметры в конструктор

:(

Comment: @Zhihar В том то и дело что ему не надо этого знать, VTT предлагает вам скрыть это знание за фабричным методом.

Comment: @Cerbo, пытаюсь разобраться (просто никогда не использовал `std::function`, `std::forward`. А можно чуть-чуть пояснить про фабричные методы и логику работы данного примера

Comment: @Zhihar Часть где `std::forward<XArgs>(args)...` относится к созданию функтора [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function) у него же несколько перегрузок конструктора.

Comment: @Zhihar Захват параметров для создания `XStatictic`, в примере не показан это вы должны снаружи сделать, например лямбдой или `std::bind`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Класс ICustomStatistics - абстрактный и требует от наследников 
//переопределить главную функцию ICustomStatistics::add
class ICustomStatistics {
public: 
    virtual ICustomStatistics* add() = 0;
};  

class  CPeriodicStatistics {
    unique_ptr<ICustomStatistics> ptr;
public:
    //работает с разными классами статистик
    CPeriodicStatistics(ICustomStatistics* p) : ptr(p) {}
    void func()
    {
        //Внутри работы CPeriodicStatistics регулярно создаются
        // и  удаляются объекты ICustomStatistics
        ptr = unique_ptr<ICustomStatistics>(ptr->add());
    }
};
void foo(CPeriodicStatistics& analyze)
{
    analyze.func();
}
```

Какие дочерные классы и когда определите и сколько их будет, дело ваше.
Ни  функции `foo` ни классу `CPeriodicStatistics` это не интересно.

```
//производные классы
class CStatistics1 : public ICustomStatistics {
    //...
public: 
    CStatistics1(const char*, const int, char) {/* ваше определение */} 
    ICustomStatistics* add() override
    { return new CStatistics1(" ", 0, 'a');}
};
class CStatistics2 : public ICustomStatistics {
    //...
public: 
    CStatistics2(unsigned, const std::string&) {/* ваше определение */ }
    ICustomStatistics* add() override
    { return new CStatistics2(0, " "); }
};
```

теперь ответ на вопрос:

> как их правильно передавать в конструктор CPeriodicStatistics и потом
>   использовать в методах класса.

Пример:

```
CPeriodicStatistics obj(new CStatistics1("SO", 1, ' '));
foo(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

@VTT, переписал твой пример в упрощённом виде для тестирования и разбора

и получил ошибки

> Error C2664   'std::function::function(std::function &&)': cannot
>   convert argument 1 from '_Ty' to
>   'std::allocator_arg_t'    params  d:\programs_example1\params\params.cpp 51
>
> Error C2664   'std::function::function(std::function &&)': cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'const char [5]' to
>   'std::allocator_arg_t'    params  d:\programs_example1\params\params.cpp 51

В чём может быть дело? Что не так?

```
class CElement1
{
protected:
    int m_x;
    int m_y;

public:
    CElement1(const int x, const int y)
        : m_x(x), m_y(y)
    {}
};

class CElement2
{
protected:
    std::string m_text;
    float       m_value;

public:
    CElement2(const std::string& text, const float value)
        : m_text(text), m_value(value)
    {}
};

template <class CBaseElement>
class CMyData
{
protected:
    std::function<CBaseElement(void)> m_objFunc;

    std::vector<CBaseElement>   m_list;

    int                         m_objCount;

public:
        template <class... Args>
        CMyData
        (
            const int objCount, 
            Args&&... args
        )
            : m_objCount(objCount), m_objFunc{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }
        {}

    void
        create
        ()
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < m_objCount; index++)
        {
            m_list.push_back({ m_objFunc() });
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto obj1 = new CMyData<CElement1>(5, 10, 11);
    auto obj2 = new CMyData<CElement2>(7, "test", 3.14);

    obj1->create();
    obj2->create();
}
```

Comment: В конструктор CMyData необходимо передавать аргументы для конструктора `std::function`, а не аргументы конструктора класса который этот функтор потом будет создавать, например `new CMyData<CElement1>(5, [](){ return CElement1{10, 11}; });`

Comment: @VTT, понял, спасибо
А правильно ли я понял, что аргументы как объект в c++ вообще получается передавать и хранить не получается?
Просто в приведённом тобой примере приходится формировать большую конструкцию с дублированием `CElement1`, `return` и килограммом скобок